# Tomcat, WARs and Multiple OSes

Tags: java, windows, linux, tomcat, war

I'm creating a WAR (`TomcatHeartbeat.war`) on my Windows machine and deploying it locally to Tomcat (v7.0.19). It deploys and runs without any errors.

I then take that same WAR and copy it ("deploy" it) to a CentOS Linux server, running the same version of Tomcat (but for Linux, obviously!) and get the following errors immediately:

```
2012-02-08 10:36:23,110 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive TomcatHeartbeat.war
2012-02-08 10:36:23,117 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig- Exception fixing docBase for context [/TomcatHeartbeat]
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    ...(rest of stack trace ommitted for brevity)
```

I suspect this is a "Windows/Linux" thing? What else would explain the fact that the WAR runs perfectly fine on my machine but not on our Linux server?

I also suspect that the remedy will be to build & deploy the WAR right there on the same machine.

Am I on-track, or way off-base here? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
The method I am using to copy the WAR from Windows to Linux is:

- Copy the file from my local disk to a network directory, which is actually on a Linux machine, yet I have access to it through Windows Explorer
- FTP the WAR from that Linux machine to the application server (both Linux machines are same version of CentOS)

Comment: "But for Linux"? Is there a different version for Linux? The remedy is to copy it correctly; a war will run on either "version" of Tomcat.

Comment: Didn't want someone to think i was running the tomcat on windows but for linux and the wrong pkg

Comment: Tomcat is Java; there's no difference I'm aware of.

Comment: but the tomcat might run in the wrong version of windows or linux

Comment: I don't even know what that means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you definitely using BIN mode for FTP? The default is ASCII, which could play havoc with a .ZIP (or, of course, a .WAR) and could introduce corruption issues. I'd look at this first of all.

This is particularly likely with a command-line FTP operation; I believe UIs, certainly on Windows, mask it nicely.